# How to create an encrypted archive in GNOME 3.22?

Tags: gnome, encryption, archive, zip, 7zip

I have a system running Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 with GNOME 3.22 and I would like to create an encrypted 7z or zip archive, however when I right-click on a file, or folder, or a group of those I just get this with the `Compress...` button:

[image: Create Archive GNOME dialog]

Unlike in previous versions, there appears to be no such option to encrypt the archive with a password. So is there still some way of doing this through GNOME without having to install a third-party utility? If there isn't, then how do you do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use file-roller to do that.

Search for it (**Archive Manager**) using the application launcher/desktop search.

Go to the top bar and select "**New archive...**".

At the bottom of the file chooser dialog you can choose a **File Format** and enter a password into the **Password** field in **Other Options**.

[image]

[Source](https://help.gnome.org/users/file-roller/stable/password-protection.html.en)

Answer (score 6):

> then how do you do it?

```
7z a file.7z ./ -p
```

It prompts you for the password.

Comment: So there is no way any more to do this through the GUI then?

Comment: I haven't found one yet.

Comment: I've added an answer with an explanation of how to enable it in the GUI. (Short version: while File Roller / Archive Manager seems to be able to deal with plain 7z files out of the box it seems it cannot create password protected 7z files  before you install the 7zip command line tools.)

Answer (score 2):

As @andrebait mentions you can use Fileroller, however there is a catch:

To encrypt 7zip archives you must install the 7zip command line tools.

On my Ubuntu machine (bionic) that is as simple as :

```
sudo apt install p7zip-ful
```

After that the password and encrypt file list options are enabled in File Roller / Archive Manager as well.

Comment: It's "p7zip-full" (double-L) but SO doesn't want me to edit only one character in the post and I'm not creative enough today to make up more changes.

Answer (score 1):

CLI solution for ZIP encryption:

```
zip -e my.zip /etc/
```

If you already got a ZIP file then we can use:

```
zipcloak my.zip
```

to encrypt `my.zip`